# Linux, improved cal, shell programming

Tags: linux, shell, math

I am working with cal for a homework assignment and i am stuck on one point.

> It is unlikely that anyone is really interested in getting a gregorian
>   calendar for a year in the first century, a time when the gregorian
>   calendar didn't even exist. Use the "windowing" strategy to allow your
>   new cal to handle years that are not the full 4 digit year. If the
>   year is in the range of 0 <= year <= 50, assume the year is really
>   2000-2050. If the year is in the range 51 <= year <= 99, assume the
>   year is really 1951-1999.

file named improvedcal.sh
call the shell with sh improvedcal.sh 1 2011 for example
code

```
case $# in 

# rando stuff

*) m=$1; y=$2 ; # 2 ags: month and year
if ((y >= 0 && y <= 50)); then  
y+=2000
elif ((y >= 51 && y <= 99)); then
y+=1900
fi;;
esac

case $m in
jan*|Jan*) m=1 ;;
feb*|Feb*) m=2 ;;
mar*|Mar*) m=3 ;;
apr*|Apr*) m=4 ;;
may*|May*) m=5 ;;
jun*|Jun*) m=6 ;;
jul*|Jul*) m=7 ;;
aug*|Aug*) m=8 ;;
sep*|Sep*) m=9 ;;
oct*|Oct*) m=10 ;;
nov*|Nov*) m=11 ;;
dec*|Dec*) m=12 ;;
[1-9]|10|11|12) ;; # numeric month
0[1-9]|010|011|012) ;; # numeric month
# *) y=$m; m="" ;; # plain year
esac

/usr/bin/cal $m $y # run cal with new inputs
```

But this is not working for some reason does anyone have any pointers for me?
It just skips right over this part for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running your script with `bash -xv`, it will help you understand what is happening.

Read also [Bash programming intro](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-10.html#ss10.2)

Comment: for some reason it is a adding it like a string, if my input is
bash -xv improvedcal.sh 1 5 
the final y is 52000 it just adds the 2000 to the end of the string instead of adding the numbers together like i want

Comment: yeah i am still having a problem it just adds it at the end of the string any hints?

Comment: The hint is in the reference I gave. Don't expect me to do all your homework. You will learn a lot more by reading and trying yourself.

Comment: im not its actually a long assignment and i have everything else done this is just one minute part i had a q about, but thank you for the reference

Comment: $((2000+y)) is what i am geting from this and i think this will prob work

Comment: I'm old enough to be your father, and I really don't understand the attitude of asking on a forum before making some effort yourself. The goal of a homework is to make you learn something. You won't learn anything if you copy a complete answer given on a forum (which your teacher probably reads).

Comment: oh i do thank you for the help but how do you assign an int to something such as just y = 3, would it be like y $[3]?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't declare a variable and directly assign to it, then it's either a string (`var=stuff`) or an array (`var=(element0 element1 element2)`). Since `y` is a string, `y+=2000` appends the string `2000` to the value.

You can declare `y` as an integer variable, then the `+=` operator will perform an addition.

```
declare -i y=$2
if ((y >= 0 && y <= 50)); then  
  y+=2000
elif ((y >= 51 && y <= 99)); then
  y+=1900
fi
```

Another way is to use the `+=` operator inside an arithmetic expression:

```
y=$2
if ((y >= 0 && y <= 50)); then  
  ((y+=2000))
elif ((y >= 51 && y <= 99)); then
  ((y+=1900))
fi
```

Or you can perform the arithmetic operation and assign the result:

```
y=$2
if ((y >= 0 && y <= 50)); then  
  y=$((y+2000))
elif ((y >= 51 && y <= 99)); then
  y=$((y+1900))
fi
```

You can write all of this in a single arithmetic expression using the `? … :` conditional operator:

```
y=$2
if ((y >= 0)); then ((y <= 50 ? y += 2000 : y <= 99 ? y+=1900 : 0)); fi
```